# Issues getting the playground hosted on my web server

Tags: google-drive-realtime-api

I'm learning the Google Drive Realtime API and as such I've downloaded the code for the playground example from the Git repo and uploaded the files to my web server.

I've been through all the client id and app id creation process on the Google Developers console and applied the resulting credentials to the app-globals.html file.

I access the playground.html and everything seems to work except I get the following issue in the browsers JS console:

```
Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "https://accounts.google.com" from accessing a frame with origin "http://##############".  The frame requesting access has a protocol of "https", the frame being accessed has a protocol of "http". Protocols must match.
```

Despite the above issue I can create a new playground doc - which is saved in my Drive and I can see all the created playground docs I have created previously.

Even double-clicking them from my Drive launches them properly on my hosted version of playground.

The main error is that nothing is logged in the activity like it is on the officially hosted version, each key press I make results in this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Expected string for text, but was: undefined
```

I must have missed something when setting this up, but I can't think what? Is it because of the https error above?

I would be grateful for any help as I'm desperate to learn this great service.

Comment: UPDATE: Collaborative List WORKS and Collaborative Map allows me to remove a selected item which works but I can't add any. Custom Object allows fires off events but doesn't seem to update with the text, instead sets everything that's changed to NULL.

Some stuff works and others doesn't (the basic string function etc.) Anyone encountered similar issues? I'm beginning to think you have might have to change more stuff then "Deploy, run that's it!"

Comment: It seems that you have a mismatch in how you are accessing the document vs how you have your configuration for Authorized Redirect URIs and JavaScript Origins defined in Google Developers console. Can you check to make sure that those URIs are accurate, and are using https?